# PullToRefreshLilstView in Android not working

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to refresh a listview in android and update the new lists in listview. Now the main thing is, now that I have imported a package and added that to my library I am getting a space in listview oncreate() but no action takes place. When I change my mobile to landscape view the listview gets extended but again, no action takes place. Any help is appreciated.

```
enter code here
<com.example.pgmed.PullToRefreshListView 
    android:id="@+id/factslistview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/line"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"



    />PullToRefreshListView factslistview;

static String id_value;
static String headline,image1,image2,image3,image4,detail,source,url,reference,isread,university,updatedat;

static String createdat;

protected static LocalActivityManager localactivity;
private MySQLiteHelper db;
 public  static int id;
 public static final String KEY_HEADLINE="Question";
 static String facts_cur_page;
 private boolean exiting;
  List<FACTS> list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facts);
   db=new MySQLiteHelper(FactsActivity.this);
   // db.openDataBase();
     final FACTS facts=new FACTS();

    factslistview = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.factslistview);
    facts_cur_page="secondpage";
    //populateList();
    //list=new ArrayList<MCQ>();
    //System.out.println("m"+m);
    //System.out.println("list");
//  String val=m.getQuestion();
     try {
        list=db.getAllFACTS();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        System.out.println("list"+list.size());
      //   for (FACTS r:list){
        //   String log = "Id: "+r.getId()+" ,image1: "+r.getImage1()+" ,image2: "+r.getImage2()+" ,image3: "+r.getImage3()+" ,image4: "+r.getImage4()+" ,detail: "+r.getDetail()+" ,url: "+r.getUrl()+" ,reference: "+r.getReference()+" ,university: "+r.getUniversity()+" ,createat: "+r.getCreateat()+" ,updatedat: "+r.getUpdateat()+" ,headline: "+r.getHeadline()+",isread: "+r.getIsread();

            // System.out.println("Headline: "+ r.getHeadline());
             //Log.d("Headline: ", log);
        // }

         factslistview.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh(){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("being refreshed");
            }
        });
```

This is my code and i have added a PullTorefreshlistview.java class

Comment: can you share some code? Otherwise it's just plain shooting in the dark...

Comment: Ok, but also add your Java code, where you add the xml widget to your code. Best is if you edit your question, and paste the code there. Would be more readable.

Comment: <com.markupartist.android.widget.PullToRefreshListView 
        android:id="@+id/factslistview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/line"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        
       
        
        />this is my layout.xml file and i imported project PullToRefreshListView.java to my library.

Comment: Did you get my point lapadets?

Comment: Guys anyone help me...Got struck in this issue